# How to I rewrite this so that its not a random number search?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im new to jquery, how would I re-write this string so that it displayed a result of 60 each time?

```
var i = Math.ceil(Math.random()*60)
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
var i = 60;
```

You should read the manual.

Answer (score 0):

To display the number 60 every time, don't use any of the `Math` functions, and just use:

```
var i = 60;
alert(i);
// or console.log(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
var i = 60;
```

What you have will give you a value from 0 to 60 inclusive (but with distribution favoring non-zero values). If you want 60, just set it to 60.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
var i = 60;
```

If you always want the result to be 60, there is no need using the random function.